# How do I execute code when a module is installed or uninstalled?

Tags: 8

Currently, I manually have to add terms one by one every time a module gets installed, and that's not efficient. I'm writing a simple module that needs to automatically install 2 terms every time the module gets installed, and remove them every time the module gets uninstalled.

From [Create taxonomy term programmatically on Drupal 8](http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/55/create-taxonomy-term-programmatically-on-drupal-8), I learned how to add terms. However, I simply don't know where to put the code. What must I do to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needs to go inside of **mymodule.install** file

```
<?php

/*
 * Implements hook_install()
 */
function mymodule_install() {

  // code that creates terms

}

/*
 * Implements hook_uninstall()
 */
function mymodule_uninstall() {

  // code that deletes terms

}
```